# Best way of parallelizing serialized counter variable inside a loop

Tags: openmp

I am trying to parallelize this 4-nested loop which contains the "serial" `counter` issue.

```
count = 0 
 for (i = 0; i < vel; i++) 
    for (n = 0; n < dist; n++) 
      for (j = 1; j <= Y; j++) 
        for (k = 1; k <= Z; k++) {

          index = index(X, j, k);           
          buffX[count] = array[index];

          index = index(Y, j, k);                 
          buffY[count] = array[index]; 
          ++count;
        }
```

I've tried very simple ideas such as:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,n,j,k,index) shared(count)   
    for (i = 0; i < vel; i++) 
        for (n = 0; n < dist; n++) 
          for (j = 1; j <= Y; j++) 
#pragma omp critical
{
          for (k = 1; k <= Z; k++) {

              index = index(X, j, k);           
              buffX[count] = array[index];
              index = index(Y, j, k);                 
              buffY[count] = array[index];
              ++count;
          }
}
```

But it does not work because of `count`. I was wondering if there is well known technique to parallelize this sort of loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straight forward way is to compute a threadlocal `count` variable from the nested loop variables:

```
for (i = 0; i < vel; i++) 
  for (n = 0; n < dist; n++) 
    for (j = 1; j <= Y; j++) 
      for (k = 1; k <= Z; k++) {
        int count = (k-1) + Z * ((j-1) + Y * (n + dist * i));
        ...
```

If you are worried for the extra cost, you can make some intermediate `count_j` in between.

An alternative is to manually collapse the loop and make `count` the primary loop index:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (count = 0; count < vel * dist * Y * Z; count++) {
    // declare locally to make sure they are threadlocal
    int k = 1 + (count % Z);
    ...
```

Note that this may affect the parallel performance of the loop positively (more iterations, better balance) or negatively (bad cache effects).

A solution where the entire loop body is only a critical section would be terrible. No threads could do any computation (or memory transfer) in parallel. Besides the critical region introduces no order guarantee, making the code wrong.

Comment: @_Zulan Yes, that will work! I wonder how I could avoid bad cache effects in a collapsed loop.